# Почему TensorFlow выше версии 1.5 не дружит с процессором AMD Athlon II?

Tags: tensorflow, lubuntu

Проблема заключается в том, что невозможно запустить TensorFlow выше версии 1.5 на данном процессоре.
Он устанавливается хорошо, ошибок нет, но запускаться не запускается. OS Lubuntu, аналогично было на Windows 7.
Выдавал ошибку при import tensorflow as tf 
Недопустимая инструкция (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что данный процессор не поддерживает инструкции [AVX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX).

Вот [issue в их репозитории](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19584).

В ней предлагают собирать tensorflow самостоятельно, например используя [`docker-tensorflow-builder`](https://github.com/hadim/docker-tensorflow-builder)

Также существует репозиторий [`tensorflow-windows-wheel`](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel), в котором находятся уже собранные версии tensorflow не требующие AVX. В частности вот [версия 1.6](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2), [версия 1.9](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.9.0/py36/CPU/sse2).